# How do you set the target location for a navmesh using a GameObject?

Tags: unity, javascript, unityscript, navmesh

I am trying to get a GameObject to navigate through a map and get to the exit.  I have created a navmesh for the map and given the player GameObject a navmesh agent. The exit is marked with a empty GameObject. Using the unity manual I made this script and atached it to the player:

```
function Start () 
{
    var agent: NavMeshAgent = GetComponent.<NavMeshAgent>();
    agent.SetDestination(GameObject.Find("exit"));
}
```

The porblem is that this script gives the error

"Assets/Scripts/enemy.js(4,29): BCE0017: The best overload for the method 'UnityEngine.NavMeshAgent.SetDestination(UnityEngine.Vector3)' is not compatible with the argument list '(UnityEngine.GameObject)'."

I think is is because unity wants a vector3 but I have given it a GameObject.
How can I get this to work with a game object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in a GameObject, yet the function wants a Vector3.

To fix this, you could pass in `transform.position`:

```
function Start () 
{
    var agent: NavMeshAgent = GetComponent.<NavMeshAgent>();
    agent.SetDestination(GameObject.Find("exit").transform.position);
}
```

Function reference [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/NavMeshAgent.SetDestination.html).